# rewrite module.exports into export default but preserve possibility to import single entity

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to achieve same functionality as:

```
module.exports = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```

...which later allows:
`import { a } from 'path/to/module'`

by using ES6 modules like (or export default):

```
export const moduleName = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}
```

so that later rather than importing whole module into other one, only part of it will be imported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use named exports instead:

```
export const a = 1;
export const b = 2;
```

Note that although this allows the consumer to do something like `import { a } from ...`, you're now not actually destructuring an object with an `a` property there, like you were doing originally with the `module.exports` syntax, you're just extracting the named export.

You can still export a default object in addition to using named exports, if you wanted:

```
export default { c: 'c', d: 'd' }
```

and then you can import with

```
import obj from '...';
const { c } = obj;
```